# transformed blob is getting file in incorrect format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I am attempting to send the user an alert when an empty file is downloaded (the server sends back the number 0 when this is the case:

```
$http.get(service)
        .success(function (response) {
            if (response === parseInt(response, 10)) {
                alert("That query had no results");
                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            }                
            else {
                var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
                window.location = objectUrl;
            }            
        });
```

The file is downloading fine but when I go to open it, I get a "file formatted incorrectly message" from excel. I know that the excel file is coming down alright because  this:

```
window.location = service
```

works just fine.

I have tried both:

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

file types. Neither one works. Thanks in advance.

edit: I thought that perhaps I needed to get the raw response (for this angular $http service) so I tried:

```
http.get(service, {
            transformResponse:
                function (d, h) {
                    return d;
                }
        })
        .success(function (response) {
            ..same as above         
        });
```

Still not working though. In fact, I put a break point on `d`, it looks like a lot of the "unrecognized" characters are being changed to question marks (I compared `d` to my network tab.) In the network tab, the characters are one way but when I check `d` they have been changed to question marks.

Answer (score 0):

The response returned from the `$http.get` is an object that includes the headers and you can't form a blob from it directly.  You can access the binary content returned by the service like this:

```
var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
```